# Angular NgModel not updating Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been coding Angular for 5 years now and in a personal project my first interaction with [(ngModel)] is driving me insane and I don't know why.
Two-way data bind should be easy and pretty straight forward. Still, this is not updating the Typescript variable. WHY is this happening? It always stays empty.

And yes, of course FormsModule is imported in app.modules

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  username:string ="";
  passwd:string ="";
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  $login(): void {
    alert(this.username);
    this.authService.login({ login: this.username, passwd: this.passwd })
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log('Login bem-sucedido!', response);
        },
        error => {
          console.error('Erro durante o login:', error);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

```
                        <form class="px-5">
                            <div class="mb-3 py-3">
                                <label for="id-login">Login</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id-login" placeholder="Login" [(ngModel)]="username">
                                <label for="id-password" class="mt-3">Senha</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control "  id="id-passwd" placeholder="Senha" [(ngModel)]="passwd">
                                <button class="mt-3 btn btn-primary" (click)="$login()">Entrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

NgModel always worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the code you shared and angular threw some errors on the console which gave me the ways to fix it!

> ERROR Error: NG01352: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the
> name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as
> 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
>
> Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first"> Example
> 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName"
> [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

You can use either one of these fixes and solve your issue!

code main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
     <form class="px-5">
          <div class="mb-3 py-3">
              <label for="id-login">Login</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id-login" placeholder="Login" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username">
              <label for="id-password" class="mt-3">Senha</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control "  id="id-passwd" placeholder="Senha" [(ngModel)]="passwd" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
              <button class="mt-3 btn btn-primary" (click)="$login()">Entrar</button>
          </div>
      </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  username: string = '';
  passwd: string = '';
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  $login(): void {
    alert(this.username);
    this.authService
      .login({ login: this.username, passwd: this.passwd })
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          console.log('Login bem-sucedido!', response);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error('Erro durante o login:', error);
        },
      });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor() {}

  login(params: any) {
    console.log('params are', params);
    return of(true);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-phprak?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fauth.service.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a lifesaver.
I've been using angular 12 at max to code at my current company, 14 at home but NEITHER The compiler nor the console logs told me that. Do you wonder why is that so?

Comment: Just edited my text with some more info, would appreciate if you had any idea! Thx my brother.

Comment: @WilliamBenseny in the console tab, check the `default levels filter` if its filtering out the console errors!